# Can you find the arc length with only the diameter and two chord lengths?

Tags: geometry

I have a $56.1$" diameter cheese vat. I need to build two supports to lay across the top. Each support is $8$" from center on either side. I found the chord lengths by $$2\sqrt{r^2-d^2}$$
where

- $r$  is the radius of the circle ($28.05$")
- $d$ is the perpendicular distance from the chord to the circle center (8")

So chord lengths on both sides of center are $53.77$".

How can I find the arc length between these two points with this information?

[image: illustration]

Comment: Since you are new, I want to give some advice about the site: **To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: Hi Jesse, to add to Zev, please upload a diagram too.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the center of the circle to be the origin of a coordinate system, then the coordinates of one of your points (point $B$ in the illustration I added to your question) has coordinates $\left(d, \sqrt{r^2-d^2}\right)$. From that you can deduce the angle $\varphi$ between the horizontal $x$ axis and the line connecting that point to the origin. That angle will satisfy

$$\tan\varphi = \frac{\sqrt{r^2-d^2}}{d}$$

[image: angle marked]

I've marked $\varphi$ in the above illustration. Now you can use that to compute the angle, and from the angle the arc length:

\begin{align*}
\varphi &= \arctan\frac{\sqrt{r^2-d^2}}{d} \\
a_{AB} &= 2r\varphi = 2r\arctan\frac{\sqrt{r^2-d^2}}{d}
\end{align*}

If you compute this using a pocket calculator, make sure you have its angle measurement mode set to radians, since a result in degrees won't work for the conversion from angle to arc length.